# Repercusions of overvolting a induction motor as a generator

Tags: motor, dc, induction-motor

I am building an EV and i want to build a genset. The truck is being designed to run off 1.7kvdc and is using 600v induction motors that we plan to overvolt. If i run a 600v motor as a generator with a load from a 1700v pack, would it be able to regerate power to the battery at the 1.7kv.

Comment: Are you REALLY running 600V motors from a 1700 VDC supply either  star or delta connected? || IF the motor runs 'properly' at 1700 DC  in I'd expect it to also regenerate at a somewhat lower voltage as Vin ~~= Vbackemf + Rmotor.Iload. ||But I'd be 'concerned' [tm] about the 1700V on 600V motors.

Answer (score 1):

A induction motor will experience magnetic saturation if subjected to severe over-voltage. To generate power to charge a 1700 volt battery pack an induction generator would need to be rated closer to 1500 volts. Designing the required electronic power conversion equipment required is not a simple task at 600 volts. It is significantly more difficult at 1500 volts.

If the frequency is raised along with the voltage, saturation is avoided, but the speed must be increased it increase the frequency. At 2.5 times rated speed, bearing life and rotor balance could present problems. Insulation voltage is also a question at 2.5 times rated voltage.

Comment: +1 magnetic saturation is going to kill this idea. An induction motor is really the same as a transformer with an odd rotating secondary. All transformer properties apply.